# Definition of Implication Statement (=>) - Equivalence of A=>B and A => (B NOT)

Tags: analysis, logic

*"Example 4: If $x \in \{ n\in \mathbb{N}| n^{2}<0\} $ then x is a sheep is true AS WELL AS the statement If $x \in \{ n\in \mathbb{N}|n^{2}<0\}$ then x is not a sheep*

Let $P$ be the statement: " $ x \in \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | n^{2} < 0\}  $ "

Let $Q$ be the statement "x is a sheep"

So doesn't this example claim that $ P \implies Q $ and $P \implies \bar{Q}$  are simultaneously true! 
As far as I can see from the truth tables which define $ \implies$, that can't be right... [as I understand it, formally, $ A \implies B $ is just a shorthand for $\bar{A} \vee B$  (NOT A OR B)]

Comment: If you happen to have $(P\implies Q)\wedge (P\implies \neg Q)$ then this implies that $P$ is false.  There is no problem with having both $P\implies Q$ and $P\implies \neg Q$ being simultaneously true statements.  See [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: Also, remember $(P\implies Q)$ is equivalent to $\neg P \vee Q$,  so you can say $(P\implies Q)\wedge (P\implies \neg Q)$ is equivalent to $(\neg P\vee Q)\wedge (\neg P\vee \neg Q)$ which is equivalent to $\neg P \vee (Q\wedge \neg Q)$ which is equivalent to $\neg P$

Comment: The point of the example is to show that any $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true as soon as $P$ is false. So if $P$ is false, then  $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true and  $P \Rightarrow \neg Q$ is also true. Look at the truth-table of the $\Rightarrow$: again, you'''ll see that  $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true as soon as $P$ is false. So you can fil in *anything* for the consequent ... that's why they chosew such silly things as 'x is a sheep'

Answer (score 3):

The point of the example is to show that any $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true as soon as $P$ is false. So if $P$ is false, then  $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true and  $P \Rightarrow \neg Q$ is also true. Look at the truth-table of the $\Rightarrow$: again, you'''ll see that  $P \Rightarrow Q$ is true as soon as $P$ is false. So you can fill in *anything* for the consequent ... that's why they chose such silly things as 'x is a sheep'

It's like when people say "If *that* is true, then I am a monkey's uncle!" ... by which they of course mean that the *that* is not true.

Answer (score 0):

From the [truth table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20p%3D%3Eq) for $P\implies Q$, notice that when $P$ is false (lines 3 and 4), it won't matter whether $Q$ is true or false, the implication $P\implies Q$ will be true. This may be more apparent if you use an alternative definition: $$P\implies Q \equiv \neg [P \land \neg Q]$$

Comment: I accept that completely! But I'm still slightly confused as to way $ P \implies \neg Q$ doesn't have the same truth table as $P \implies Q$... - [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+p%3D%3E+not+q) so that in some way, they aren't equivalent?

Comment: Ah, I guess what I mean is, how do I know that P is false?

Comment: @thesundayscientist 1. $P \implies \neg Q$ is not equivalent. Compare  the truth tables.  2. I didn't say that $P$ is false. I said, "WHEN $P$ is false..."

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $P\to Q$ and $P\to\neg Q$ are **not** equivalent statements.   Their columns in a [truth table](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+%7C+%7BP+implies+Q,+P+implies+not+Q%7D) are not identical.   However, they *may* have simultaneouly the same evaluation for certain rows -- those are where $P$ is false.

$$\begin{array}{|c|c} \hline P & Q & P\to Q & P\to \neg Q\\ \hline \top & \top & \top & \bot \\ \hdashline \top & \bot & \bot & \top \\ \hdashline \bot & \top & \top & \top & \bigstar\\ \hdashline \bot & \bot & \top & \top & \bigstar \\ \hline \end{array}$$

So $(P\to Q)\gets\hspace{-2ex}\to(P\to \neg Q)$ is not a tautology, but $(P\to Q)\wedge(P\to \neg Q)$ *may* be true, and in which case the inference is $\neg P$.